# How to resize webview in webkit GTK

Tags: c++, unix, webkit, gtk, gtk3

I have recently started to work on webkitgtk .
Currently i am facing issue while trying to resize the webview in webkitgtk.

**Current implementation:**

I have one main window **GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_plug_new(MYwinId);** 
and then I am creating a webview using

**WebKitWebView *webView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());**

Then i am adding the newly created webview to main window using 
**gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(main_window ), GTK_WIDGET(webView));**

**Current Issues i am facing: Resizing webview**

I am trying to resize this webview which was created.
I tried searching for any API call to resize from my application ,but i am unlucky to find one .

Anyone kindly help me out to find any API call to resize my webview from my application layer.

**BackGround:**

I am trying to resize webview because when I click on the text field in the webview a virtual keyboard will pop up which is hiding the text field . So my idea is to resize the webview so i can move the text field above the keyboard area.

Comment: Not sure why GtkPlug is being used here

Comment: i am using GtkPlug as my main window because to use window , which is getting created by other module/layer.

Comment: That does complete things, so from which process are you trying to resize it? I would suggesting resizing the GtkSocket you connect it do would be best.

Comment: And I expect you already know this but GtkPlug/GtkSocket are X only so as the world moves towards Wayland you may have a problem